# Kubernes Job Curl URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Tags: kubernetes, curl

I prepared a job yaml file and deployed it. Job will send post request to grafana api create user method. However it returns error.

error: "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"

How Should I change command lines?

yaml file:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: grafanauser-ttl
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: grafanauser
        image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0
        command:
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-ec'          
            - 'curl -X POST "http://admin:admin@grafana.utility.svc.cluster.local/api/admin/users" \
                -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d \
                "{"name":"test","email":"test@localhost.com","login":"test","password":"test","OrgId": 1}"'
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `curl` command isn't properly formated that's why you're seeing this issue. There's a couple of other threads regarding this error message you're receiving from curl.

However a quick fix would be to supply the curl in a single line. The following would work:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: grafanauser-ttl
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: grafanauser
          image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -ec
            - 'curl -X POST "http://admin:admin@grafana.utility.svc.cluster.local/api/admin/users" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{"name":"test","email":"test@localhost.com","login":"test","password":"test","OrgId": 1}"'
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I don't have the service running, but you shouldn't receive the curl error anymore:

```
$ kubectl logs grafanauser-ttl-xjt2q
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grafana.utility.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 0):

You shell command line translates to

```
curl -X POST "http://admin:admin@grafana.utility.svc.cluster.local/api/admin/users"                 -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d                 "{"name":"test","email":"test@localhost.com","login":"test","password":"test","OrgId": 1}"
```

which will make shell strip away all the quotes:

```
curl -X POST http://admin:admin@grafana.utility.svc.cluster.local/api/admin/users -H Content-Type:application/json -d {name:test,email:test@localhost.com,login:test,password:test,OrgId: 1}
```

and curl will choke on the final `1}` (its last argument)

Try rewriting it using YAML block literal:

```
        command:
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-ec'          
            - |
                curl -X POST "http://admin:admin@grafana.utility.svc.cluster.local/api/admin/users" \
                -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d \
                '"{"name":"test","email":"test@localhost.com","login":"test","password":"test","OrgId": 1}'
```